# Escape quotes, asterisk and double quotes in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I writing a **bash script** with variables with output of command, in this case, return a path, but doesnt works. I tried too with "eval" but the problem is the quotes, asterisk, double quotes, ... i tried escape with \ , but doesnt works.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks you

```
cert = $(find /my/path/ -name 'cert*.pem' -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1)
echo ${cert}
```

Comment: Remove the blanks around the `=`.

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).

Comment: `but doesnt works` what does that mean? What happens? What does not happen? What did you expect to happen? Please post the exact error message, if any.

Comment: Perfect! Removing blanks around the = now works, and return the path expected! Thanks u